# Wouldn't time travel also require space travel to be practical?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, time-travel

If we somehow move back in time, say 6 months back, earth would be on the opposite side of the sun relative to its position in the present.

Earth is moving relative to sun. Sun is moving relative to the galactic center. If I am not mistaken, the galaxy is also moving in space.

Then, we travel back in time, like what they show in TV and movies, we wouldn't be on earth. Right? We would be in the void of space. Or by a very slim chance into some other celestial object. Did we just leave earth without accounting for the gravitational potential energy?

Comment: Correct.  "Time travel" is a fictional concept only.

Comment: Space-time travel :)